# Appending strings received within a subscriber method?

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port, append, grasshopper

In the code below, the strings received within `myReceivedLines` appear when connecting with my serial port (when `connecttodevice` is true). However they disapear when I launch another command (when `homeall` is true).

I added the field called `myReceivedLines` within the class so that I could use the method `String.Add()` to all the feedback received and commands sent (having like a console within the program).

Why does the feedback dispear when a command is sent and how can I make sure all the strings stay in the variable `myReceivedLines`? Is the string going to `myReceivedLine` disapearing because they happen within a subscriber method? How do I solve that?

NB: GH_DataAccess.SetDataList(Int32, IEnumerable) is a method from the Kernel a software called [Grasshopper](http://grasshopper3d.com) to assign values to an output (it has to be used within the GH_Component.SolveInstance() method which is also from this Kernel), I am using this to visualise myReceivedLines.

**code:**

```
 public class SendToPrintComponent : GH_Component
    {
        //Fields
        List<string> myReceivedLines = new List<string>();
        SerialPort port;

        //subscriber method for the port.DataReceived Event
        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            while (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    myReceivedLines.Add(sp.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
        {
           //Opening the port
            if (port == null)
            {
                string selectedportname = default(string);
                DA.GetData(1, ref selectedportname);
                int selectedbaudrate = default(int);
                DA.GetData(2, ref selectedbaudrate);


                //Assigning an object to the field within the SolveInstance method()
                port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

                //Enables the data terminal ready (dtr) signal during serial communication (handshaking)
                port.DtrEnable = true;
                port.WriteTimeout = 500;
                port.ReadTimeout = 500;
            }

            //Event Handling Method
            bool connecttodevice = default(bool);
            DA.GetData(3, ref connecttodevice);

            **if (connecttodevice == true)**
            {
                if (!port.IsOpen)
                {
                    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                    DA.SetDataList(0, myReceivedLines);
                    port.Open();

                }
            }
            else
            if (port.IsOpen)
                {
                    port.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                    port.Close();
                }


            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                DA.SetData(1, "Port Open");
            }

            //If the port is open do all the rest
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                bool homeall = default(bool);
                DA.GetData(5, ref homeall);


                //Home all sends all the axis to the origin
                **if (homeall == true)**
                {
                    port.Write("G28" + "\n");
                    myReceivedLines.Add("G28" + "\n");
                    DA.SetDataList(2, myReceivedLines);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                DA.SetData(1, "Port Closed");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It is not visible from the posted code, you should post whole class. Are your running threads to send/receive text? If its thread, you will need use lock before updating your string.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the answer, there was a problem in the code display. I am not sure what `running thread` means.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to append to a string, I would reccomend a StringBuilder object.

Or the less cleaner resolution, use the += operator,

```
string s = "abcd";
s+="efgh";
Console.WriteLine(s); //s prints abcdefgh
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, what is a `StringBuilder` object?

Comment: A StringBuilder is a type of extended string object that provides much more functionality than a regular string object.

It provides methods such as .Append (which is what I believe you are looking for above) as well as many other useful functions usually carried out on strings.

This webpage provides useful examples and explanations http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder

Comment: Thanks you Stephen, I am not sure how `StringBuilder.Append` is different from `Strings.Add`. Can you please clarify that? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your variables (myReceivedLines and port) are not static. I'm not sure if you want them to be static because I can't see how your using SendToPrintComponent class.
And could you explain DA.SetDataList(0, myReceivedLines); or better yet include the code because the problem could be there...

Comment: Thanks @DjSol, I removed `static` from the fields, sorry for the confusion. I have included almost all the code here. `IGH_DataAccess.SetDataList(Int32, IEnumerable)` is a method from the Kernel a software called [Grasshopper](http://grasshopper3d.com) to assign values to an output (it has to be used within the `GH_Component.SolveInstance()` method which is also from this Kernel), I am using this to visualise `myReceivedLines`.